# Display a specific <div> content at setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, setinterval

In the below code I am making an API call to my backend node.js app using `setTimeout()` which calls my AJAX at every 5 seconds. Inside my AJAX success I am displaying `divContent1` & `divContent2` based on certain condition which should execute at least once. After that only `divContent2` should be visible at each `setTimeout()` calls.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){         
    $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route1",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType:'json',                                         
             success: function(res) {
                 //Some Task               

            }
        });   
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        const route2 = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route2",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { var1: val1 },
            success: function (res) { 

            // Various tasks
            if(res.flag){
                $("#divContent1").hide();
                $("#divContent2").show();
            }
            else{
                $("#divContent1").show();
            }

            //Functions that handle div content data

            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#divContent1").hide(); 
                $("#divContent2").hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(route2,5000);
            },
        });
    };
    $(function(){
        route2();
    })
    });
});                
</script>
```

The setTimeout() calls the entire `route2` function which handles all the display and insertion of `div` content. However, the ask is to only display `divContent2` from the second call.

Looking for a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

> The setTimeout() calls the entire route2 function which handles all
>   the display and insertion of div content. However, the ask is to only
>   display divContent2 from the second call.

You're calling `route2` recursively with `setTimeout(route2,5000);` under `complete`. So this will run infinitely as `complete` occur each time an ajax call is completed (wether `success` or `error`). So what you can do is to create a timer and clear it after the second execution, something like this:

```
   var ctr = 0, timer =0;
   const route2 = function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (res) { 
         //Write you logic based on ctr
        }
        complete: function() {
            if(ctr>0){
              clearTimeout(timer)
            }else{
              timer = setTimeout(route2,5000);
              ctr = ctr+ 1;
            }

        },
     });
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Will an external variable be enough? Just define it in the outer context and set/check it to choose the behavior:

```js
// before declaring button click handler
var requestDoneAtLeastOnce = false;

// ...
// somewhere in success handler
success: function (res) {
    if (!requestDoneAtLeastOnce) {
        requestDoneAtLeastOnce = true;
        // do something that belongs only to handling the first response
    }
    else {
        // this is at least the second request, the other set of commands belongs here
    }
}
```